# Use PowerShell to determine size of a string in bytes

Tags: string, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to write messages to a message queue, which has a message size limit on it. Before writing a message to the queue, I need to know how many bytes a string is.

How can I figure out how many bytes the string is, so I can perform a size comparison, before writing to the queue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to this depends on the text encoding you're using.

You can use the static method `GetByteCount()` on a few different text encodings. Assuming you're using UTF-8 text encoding, you can reference the `UTF8` static property on the `System.Text.Encoding` class, to obtain a reference to the `UTF8Encoding` class.

Here's an example, where we retrieve a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object, convert it to a JSON representation, and then determine how many bytes it uses, given a UTF8 encoding.

```
$Process = Get-Process -Name System | ConvertTo-Json
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetByteCount($Process)
```

Here's the same example, but changing the text encoding to ASCII.

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetByteCount($Process)
```

If your input string doesn't contain any Unicode characters, you should get the same result for both ASCII and UTF-8 byte counts.

**NOTE**: The `System.Text.Encoding` base class declares a virtual method named `GetByteCount()`, however it's up to the child classes (eg. `UTF8Encoding`) to actually implement this method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3739zdy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, so, what is the encoding that you're using in the message? Both the sender and receivers have to know and use it. ("UTF-8 characters": UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode characters set, as is UTF-16, which is the encoding for the String and datatype. So, all of your characters are Unicode.)